# Rearranging Dashboard meta boxes with use of plugin/functions.php

Tags: plugin-development, metabox, dashboard

I know how to remove meta boxes from dashboard, also how to add new ones, but is there a method that allows to rearrange them, for example move from `side` position to `normal` with use of functions.php or a plugin?

I know that it would require to fire only once somehow, to allow user to rearrange elements in the future, but in that case, it might just do it every time it loads - elements on dashboard are limited and functionality to rearrange them can be disabled completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add_meta_box` has a the following *placement* parameters:

```
$context
'normal', 'advanced', 'side'

$priority 
'high', 'core', 'default' 'low'
```

For `$context` the difference between *normal* and *advanced* is that *normal* will be placed on the page before *advanced*.

The `$priority` determines the hierarchy but is overridden when dragged by the user. You can [disable the drag and drop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/disable-dragging-of-meta-boxes) functionality.

Furthermore `do_meta_boxes` can be used to place (output) the registered meta box, for example if you want to place the meta box above the WYSIWYG editor you can use it in a function which fires `edit_form_after_title`.

If you only want to run an action once you can some trickery with `did_action`, for example:

```
function action_trickery_115819(){

    if(did_action('admin_init') === 1) {
    //some action to run once
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'action_trickery_115819' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_meta_boxes
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/did_action

Comment: The part with run once is quite interesting, but I can't take the knowledge with meta boxes to the working solution... how 'do_meta_boxes' could be used in this case... or perhaps You are sugesting to remove the metaboxes and add them again to new positions somehow ;).

Comment: Yes if you want to change positions you have to remove them and then re-add them.