# Disable drag metaboxes, create many functions using js not to work!

Tags: jquery, metabox, javascript

when i Disable dragging metaboxes in admin, it seems to make some problems.
when i use this code:

```
function disable_drag_metaboxs() {
    wp_deregister_script('postbox');
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_drag_metaboxs');
```

i have some strange problem. when i uploading featured image into post or page all works. but when i try to click on the remove image link from the post/page nothings happened and i get error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WPRemoveThumbnail is not defined
```

anyone know some solution for this bug?

Thanks!

Comment: no one see this bug?

Comment: [have you seen this question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/disable-dragging-of-meta-boxes) that script isn't only for metabox dragging, so it's not a bug that you've broken other things by removing it.